# GWT: reading from a CSV file on the Server

Tags: java, gwt

I try to convert an old Applet to a GWT Application but I encountered a problem with the following function:

```
    private String[] readBrandList() {
    try {
        File file = new File("Brands.csv");
        String ToAdd = "Default";
        BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        ArrayList<String> BrandName = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (ToAdd != null) {
            ToAdd = (read.readLine());
            BrandName.add(ToAdd);
        }
        read.close();
        String[] BrandList = new String[BrandName.size()];
        for (int Counter = 0; Counter < BrandName.size(); Counter++) {
            BrandList[Counter] = BrandName.get(Counter);
        }
        return BrandList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now apparently The BufferedReader isn't supported by GWT and I find no way to replace it other than writing all entries into the code which would result in a maintenance nightmare.

Is there any function I'm not aware of or is it just impossible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read this file on the server side of your app, and then pass the results to the client using your preferred server-client communication method. You can read and pass the entire file, if it's small, or read/transfer in chunks if the file is big.